# problem with using jquery

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, alert

I am new to magento and know only basic thing about it.

I want to show a popup on my page. 
I just add alert after document.redy event on that .phtml file
but the popup wont appear after loading that page.
also when I view source code of that file it will not show me my alert code.

i am not getting the point why it happening. 
can you please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Have you clear your Magento cache before reloading your page `rm -rf var/cache/*`?
Are other elements in your phtml file appear on your page?

Comment: whether you are writing this code in the new module?

Comment: can you please add code how you add .phtml file

Comment: please add code that you try to appear popup

Comment: Give a try to replace `$` with `jQuery`.